# Session optimization in Jetty + Wicket

Tags: performance, optimization, jetty

Is there a way to swap sessions onto disk with jetty if they are idle for n.n. minutes?

It is under investigation, but we suspect that we have many idle users logged in with large session size. So, while they are doing nothing, their session could be pushed onto disk.

Is there a setting or utility or way to achieve this?

```
We are using wicket+jetty.
```

Simply shortening session destroy timeout is not an option.

Comment: You could also have a look at java melody (monitoring); with this you can actually see the size of your sessions and the size of wicket part of the session.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're running Jetty 7, the answer is yes.

Because it's possible to configure & run Jetty in multiple ways, it's pretty hard to give a definitive answer about how to turn this on in your scenario.

The outcome you want it to call "setIdleSavePeriod" on the "HashSessionManager" with a non-zero value (the number of seconds a session should be idle before it is pushed to disk)

If you're running your server with the default jetty.xml then you'll need to add something like (untested):

```
<Configure class="org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
  .
  .
  .
  <Set name="sessionHandler">
    <New class="org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler">
      <Arg>
        <New class="org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.HashSessionManager">
          <Set name="storeDirectory">your/chosen/directory/goes/here</Set>
          <Set name="idleSavePeriod">300</Set>
        </New>
      </Arg>
    </New>
  </Set>
  .
  .
  .
</Configure>
```

Comment: Ah, we are using jetty6. I will try overriding HashSessionManager.